# How do I re-direct the user to the success view of a Spring controller when they receive an error/validation message?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a bit of a problem that I cannot figure out a solution to.

I display an error message to the user if they attempt to download an invoice before the download of a previous invoice has completed. The invoices are displayed in a list of invoice search results (i.e. the success view), which has been displayed after the user did a search for invoices (i.e. the form view). Upon attempting to download the invoice, the app goes through a report controller, and this is where I perform the checking of whether or not a previous invoice is still being generated or not. If it is, I need to re-direct the user back to the invoice search results page, with an error message displayed. Currently, my redirect is taking them back to the search form (the form view). Does anyone know how I can redirect them to the results page (success view)? I need a generic solution, ideally, as other reports can be downloaded from other parts of the application.

We have Java 7 with Spring 3.1, and this part of the code is quite old so it uses XML-based bean configuration rather than annotations. If anyone can think of perhaps a better solution, that would also be much appreciated too.

Many thanks.

Edit: Just to add a bit more detail - I need a generic solution if possible - the redirect happens in a different controller to the one that I am attempting to re-direct back to, so I don't have access to the command class or the like - only the HTTP servlet request and response. (I've probably answered my own question here, as it doesn't sound possible to do without the command object!).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ModelAndView`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html) and when you return you can decide where to redirect by doing something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/yourMapping")
public ModelAndView endpoint(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest    httpServletRequest) {
    // your logic here
    String target = "redirect:" + yourUrl;
    return new ModelAndView(target, model);
}
```

hope that helps

Comment: great edit guys, you removed link to the documentation of `ModelAndView`

Comment: my apologies, didn't notice what you did to the link :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way of achieving this in conjunction with a `ModelAndView` is by using [`RedirectAttributes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html)

Example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/yourMapping")
public ModelAndView endpoint(
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
        final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes
        ) {
    // your logic here

    ModelAndView mov = new ModelAndView();

    String target = "redirect:" + yourUrl;

    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("error", true);
    redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("added", "Error message here");

    mov.setViewName(target);

    return mov;
}
```

Then in your `JSP` you can do something like:

```
<c:if test="${error == true}">
    <c:out value="${message}" />
</c:if>
```

Comment: If you downvote an answer, consider leaving a response as to why you downvoted, because it really makes no sense otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

this is what you want to do 
need to re-direct the user back to the invoice search results page, with an error message displayed. if they attempt to download an invoice before the download of a previous invoice has completed

to achieve this you will have to redirect to the controller which creates the success view and you need to include an error message you cannot redirect to the view/jsp directly because then the model would be empty and there would be no results to display

code to redirect to the controller

```
public String processRegistration(Model model) {

// if(make your check here) (

model.addAttribute("error", "error message");
return "redirect:/yoururl/{error}";
}
}
```

in the receiving controller

you can retrieve the error message as

```
public String handle(Model model) {
  String errormsg = (String) model.asMap().get("error");
set this in the model as an attribute// may not be required but check 
and procceed with the method to create the view 

}
```

in the jsp you can display the error message as mentioned in the code above

```
<c:if test="${error == true}">
    <c:out value="${message}" />
</c:if>
```